# If $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ is split, we say that $B \cong A \oplus C$. Is there a reason we take the direct sum rather than the product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

I'm studying some commutative algebra and a solution to an exercise(concerning commutative $R$-modules) relies on the isomorphisms $$\text{Hom}(C, A \oplus C) \cong \text{Hom}(C, A \times C) \cong \text{Hom}(C, A) \times \text{Hom}(C, C)$$
where the first isomorphism takes the canonical $A \oplus C \cong A \times C$ and the second uses the fact that Hom preserves products in the second variable. I figured I could do this because finite direct sums and finite products are naturally isomorphic, right? This kind of operation with Hom seemed too good to be true. Does this actually work?

The reason I ask is that this solution would be greatly simplified if I took the sequence being split to mean $B \cong A \times C$ instead. That way, I wouldn't have to worry about the first isomorphism.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the difference between $A\oplus C$ and $A\times C$?

Comment: How do you define *split*? There is right-split and left-split. These are equivalent, but dual properties, which therefore means that showing a product or co-product (i.e., sum) take sthe same effort, depending on where you start.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven $\oplus$ is a direct sum and $\times$ is a product. In finite cases, I was under the impression that they are the same.

Comment: Indeed, they are the same in the finite setting :) thus I was confused why you write isomorphic instead of equal.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Well, either is defined only up to canonical isomorphism, so they are canonically isomorphic. (And strictly speaking, product and sum are defined as objects together with certain morphisms, which are different)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I see. I generally consider split sequences of modules to be all three definitions at the same time, as per the splitting lemma. That's interesting that they yield different products though. I will look into that, thanks!

Comment: @HagebvonEitzen Well, yes, if you consider an abstract product/direct sum. However, in the category of $R$-modules I would take the "usual" one (coming from the cartesian product). I see no reason to obscure the situation by "abstract nonesense".

Comment: The fact that you are using $0$ instead of $1$ suggests that the groups are additive and abelian, rather than multiplicative. As such, $\oplus$ is taken as the (bi)product, even though it is isomorphic to the direct product for finitely many factors.

Comment: @DanielApsley That's a good way toview it. Perhaps one shoul duse left-split, right-split, direct sum, direct product as four equivalent statements in the splitting lemma, but that sounds a bit silly when the last two are equivalent anyway

Comment: One should probably mention that this is an elementary feature of additive categories: finite products are canonically isomorphic to finite coproducts.

Comment: @QiZhu That is fascinating! I suppose that was to be expected in some ways but that is very nice.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen isn't right-split (i.e. the existence of a section $C\to B$) already sufficient to invoke a retraction $B\to A$ s.t. the SES is also left-split in any short exact sequence?

Comment: @Zest In the case of abelian objects, yes. In the case of groups in general, no. One gives the semidirect product whereas the other gives the direct product.

Comment: @DanielApsley thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you know that the categorical concepts of *product* and *sum* (or *coproduct*) are defined by universal properties which are dual to each other.

Consider a three term sequence $A \stackrel{f}{\to} B \stackrel{g}{\to} C$ in a category $\mathcal C$.

1. Given a morphism $r : B \to A$, we get a unique morphism $\phi : B \to A \times C$ such that $\pi_A \circ \phi =r$ and $\pi_C \circ \phi = g$. Here $\pi_A : A \times C \to A$ and $\pi_C : A \times C \to C$ are the "projection" morphisms belonging to the categorical product of $A$ and $C$. If $\mathcal C$ is the category of $R$-modules, the sequence $0 \to A \stackrel{f}{\to} B \stackrel{g}{\to} C \to 0$ is exact and $r \circ f = id_A$, then one can show that $\phi$ is an isomorphism.
2. Given a morphism $i : C \to B$, we get a unique morphism $\psi :  A \oplus C \to C$ such that $\psi \circ \iota_A  = f$ and $\psi \circ \iota_C  = i$. Here $\iota_A : A \to A \oplus C$ and $\iota_C : C \to A \oplus C$ are the "embedding" morphisms belonging to the categorical sum of $A$ and $C$. If $\mathcal C$ is the category of $R$-modules, the sequence $0 \to A \stackrel{f}{\to} B \stackrel{g}{\to} C \to 0$ is exact and $g \circ i = d_C$, then one can show that $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

As Qi Zhu mentions in his comment, in additive categories finite products are canonically isomorphic to finite sums. Thus you may interpret $A \oplus C$ and $A \times C$ as the same *object*. In fact, both can be taken as the set of all pairs $(a,c)$ with $a \in A, c \in C$ with the usual algebraic operations making it an $R$-module. But be aware that the categorical status is different which does not become transparent if we work on the "naive" level of sets.